# vuejs push checkbox values to URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I am building a filter with vue js3. I want to push the user selected values to URL and I am watching changes in watch

My checkbox are not working, I have an array and I want to loop all course and make dynamic filter and push its value to URL.
My select options are working and it push values to Url, My Url is like this:
`http://localhost:8080/filter?sort=latest` when i choose latest from Url

I have few courses in array. I want to loop it and make a dynamic checkbox
and when user checks it, i want to push it value to URL.
I need this type of URL:
`http://localhost:8080/filter?sort=latest&course=php&course=js` when user select latest, php and js options

So far I have done

```
    <h3>Choose multiple</h3>
        <div v-for="(name,index) in courses" :key="index">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="filter.course" >{{name}}
       
       </div>

  
  
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{

            courses:[],

            filter: {
                
                course:''
    
           }
        }
    },

    watch:{
        filter:{
            handler(){
            this.$router.push({
                query:this.filter
            })
            },
            deep:true
        }
    }
   
}
</script>
```

Only the problem here is i am not able to push checkbox values in the  URL

Fixed: This was fixed by changing course:'' to array  course:[]

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do, having multiple checkboxes using the same v-model

Comment: either remove the question, or post how you solved it in an answer :p

Comment: i tried to delete, but it shows warning that i may be blocked if i delete it

Comment: oh, ok - never asked a question, so I didn't know removing your own question was forbidden!! How about you add an answer then, to show how you fixed it

Comment: updated, mentioned answer above. thanks